# Access elements of boost tokenizer

Tags: c++, boost, tokenize

I'm trying to assign columns of a file using boost to a std::map.  I would like to assign element 0  from each line to the index and element 2 to the value.  Is there a way to do this without an iterator? The addr_lookup line does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream myfile("core_info_lowbits.tab", std::ios_base::in);
  std::string line;
  typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> >  tokenizer;
  boost::char_separator<char> sep(" ");
  std::map<std::string, unsigned int> addr_lookup;

  while ( std::getline (myfile,line) )
  {
    tokenizer tokens(line, sep);
    //Line below does not work
    addr_lookup[*tokens.begin()] = boost::lexical_cast<unsigned int> (*(tokens.begin()+2));
    for (tokenizer::iterator tok_iter=tokens.begin();
         tok_iter != tokens.end(); ++tok_iter)
          std::cout << *tok_iter << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: So I converted it to a std::vector which works but not sure if it is good programming style: std::vector<std::string> s_tmp(tokens.begin(), tokens.end());

Comment: because you can increment iterator of a `std::vector`

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to advance the iterator using `+`, which is not possible

Use:

```
tokenizer::iterator it1,it2= tokens.begin();
it1=it2;
++it2; ++it2;

addr_lookup[*it1] = boost::lexical_cast<unsigned int> (*it2);
```

Or simply,

```
tokenizer::iterator it1,it2= tokens.begin();
it1=it2;
std::advance(it2,2);
addr_lookup[*it1] = boost::lexical_cast<unsigned int> (*it2);
```

Comment: Needs to be incremented twice (OP says element at index 2).

Comment: What about `std::advance`? :)